# How to get only a part of a line using regex group in python?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

How to get only a part of a line using regex group in python ?
I have a database of one entry per line and I want to split it into files according to month and day data at the beginning of a line but I want only to output a line without first 21 characters.
Here is a quick sample of the database:

```
01-01-1989-06:30:00| Stefan Reinartz; 1.1.1989; 06:30; +01; Engelskirchen,Germany; 50n59; 7e24; M;
01-01-1996-08:40:00| Dawid Kwiatkowski; 1.1.1996; 08:40; +01; Gorzów Wielkopolski,Poland; 52n44; 15e15; M;
01-01-2001-01:30:00| Liam Flockhart; 1.1.2001; 01:30; -08; San Diego,California; 32n43; 117w09; M;
01-02-1467-00:20:00| King of Poland Sigismund I the Old; 2.1.1467; 00:20; +00:21:33; Kozienice,Poland; 51n35; 21e33; M;
01-02-1746-09:00:00| Duke of Rambouillet Louis Marie; 2.1.1746; 09:00; -00:03:41; Madrid,Spain; 40n24; 3w41; M;
01-02-1784-01:00:00| Duke of Saxe-Coburg and Gotha Ernst I; 2.1.1784; 01:00; +00:10:58; Coburg,Germany; 50n15; 10e58; M;
```

Desired output File 01-01.zbs:

```
Stefan Reinartz; 1.1.1989; 06:30; +01; Engelskirchen,Germany; 50n59; 7e24; M;
Dawid Kwiatkowski; 1.1.1996; 08:40; +01; Gorzów Wielkopolski,Poland; 52n44; 15e15; M;
Liam Flockhart; 1.1.2001; 01:30; -08; San Diego,California; 32n43; 117w09; M;
```

Output File 01-02.zbs:

```
King of Poland Sigismund I the Old; 2.1.1467; 00:20; +00:21:33; Kozienice,Poland; 51n35; 21e33; M;
Duke of Rambouillet Louis Marie; 2.1.1746; 09:00; -00:03:41; Madrid,Spain; 40n24; 3w41; M;
Duke of Saxe-Coburg and Gotha Ernst I; 2.1.1784; 01:00; +00:10:58; Coburg,Germany; 50n15; 10e58; M;
```

I used the beginning to sort them by each day of the year and to split the file accordingly. But I don't want to output the first 21 chars of each line so I am trying to use regex group to do this, like this:

```
re.search("^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}| (.*)",line[0])
re.search("^.{21}(.*)",line[0])
```

But, how to use the group (.*) \1 to only output that part ?
Is even regex needed to do this ?

Here is whole code: I am a very beginner to python so the code is probably quite wrong:

```
import re
with open("database.txt") as f: 
    pstring='' #previous line string beginning
    astring='' #actual line string beginning
    try:
        out = open(re.search("^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}",line[0]) + ".zbs", "w")
        for line in f:
            astring = re.search("^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-",line[0])
            if not pstring = astring:
                out.write(line)
                pstring = re.search("^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-",line[0])
                if out: out.close()
                out = open(re.search("^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}",line[0]) + ".zbs", "w")
            else: 
                pstring = re.search("^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-",line[0])
                out.write(line)
    finally:
        out.close()
```

Best regards.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I see that you repeatedly perform the same re.search for the same line. You might consider storing the result in a variable, and use that variable in stead.

Comment: You open the first file using a with statement, which is good. However, for the second file you don't use a with statement. Therefore you'll have to close the file yourself. Unfortunately, that close() command fails, and the error message masks the message which was about to describe the real error ...

Comment: i'm not quite sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but line[0] gives you only the very first character of the current line. if you want to get rid of the first 21 characters, then you can simply use line[21:]. you don't need any regex to achieve this.

Comment: You are using a try clause without an except clause. If you don't plan to catch the exception, why bother using the try statement?
The (second) open statement fails, because you try to use the `line` variable before you read anything into it.

Comment: actually, using try-finally (without except) is ok in general (to ensure that some resource is released), although a with block would be much nicer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a single line in your file:

```
line = "01-01-1989-06:30:00| Stefan Reinartz; 1.1.1989; 06:30; +01; Engelskirchen,Germany; 50n59; 7e24; M;"
```

If you want to get rid of the first 21 characters of a line, then you can simply use what is referred to as slicing as follows:

```
>>> print(line[21:])
Stefan Reinartz; 1.1.1989; 06:30; +01; Engelskirchen,Germany; 50n59; 7e24; M;
```

(Have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) site for more details about retrieving substrings via slicing.)

Now, if you need to extract parts of such a line, then you can indeed make use of regular expressions. To get the parts of the date, as you mentioned, you can use, e.g., a pattern with named groups as follows:

```
import re
p = r"[^\;]+; (?P<day>[0-9]+)\.(?P<month>[0-9]+)\.(?P<year>[0-9]+)"
m = re.match(p, line)
```

The matched groups may then be accessed like this:

```
>>> m.group("day")
'1'
>>> m.group("month")
'1'
>>> m.group("year")
'1989'
```

(You can, of course, get the date more easily by extracting it right from the beginning of a line, but this is just an example that demonstrates the use of named group.)

Comment: I understand it better now but what if I want to read only first five characters ?

Comment: Then you use line[:5]. Check out this tutorial on indexing/slicing strings: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3